# How to make VSCode recognize php snippets when I code between <?php ?> in a blade type page?

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

I have **Laravel Blade Snippets** extension installed in my VSCode.
But when I'm coding at a blade type page, if I use the php tag **< ?php ?>**, the VSCode doesn't autocomplete php code.

For example, in the code below, when I type **str_r**, it should autocomplete showing the functions started with **str_r**. In this case one of the options should be **str_replace**.

But instead, it does nothing.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

`<?php ?>` is **not** part of the blade snippets. `@php @endphp` is.

Simply type **:php** and **press enter**, this will insert `@php @endphp` tag and later it will be converted into `<?php ?>` when complied.

Comment: Thanks for answering!

I typed :php and it was inserted `@php @endphp` tag as you said.

But when I type str_r the vscode is not autocompleting the functions started with str_r (for exemple str_replace() is one of them)

Comment: @LucasCamargo not every command with be auto-completed. You will have to add relevant extensions for that. Try to add `PHP IntelliSense`, `PHP Intelephense` and then try str_r...